# Primality test proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image]

Can anybody help me in understanding the underlined part in this image.

$q^k$ is coprime to $a^{n-q}$ becuase if it was not the case then $q|a^{n-q}$ which implies $q|a$ which is a contradiction to the fact that gcd$(a,n)=1$.

Is this argument correct?

Answer (score 3):

We write $\binom{n}{q}=\frac{n!}{q!(n-q)!}=\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-q+1)}{q!}.$  The only number in the numerator that is divisible by $q$ is $n$ (it's a product of $q$ consecutive numbers).  But $q^k|n$ and $q^{k+1}\not|n$, while $q|q!$ so $q^k$ cannot divide their quotient.

Your argument for $a^{n-q}$ is correct.

Comment: thanks. I was missing the fact that only number in numerator that is divisible by $q$ is $n$.